# O que colocar na variável $.post ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Oi, não sou muito bom em javascript,ajax,jquery e json ainda estou aprendendo e lembrando que eu já pesquisei muito, mas não consegui fazer o que eu quero. É o seguinte meu projeto está em MVC com url amigável. Na página tem um caixa de texto que valida o cep e exibe os valores do frete isso eu fiz com PHP, mas eu tive que colocar duas opções com radio para escolher o tipo de frete, eu queria que no momento que clicasse no tipo de frete por exemplo "pac" ou "sedex" ele atualizava a página e enviasse esse valor para uma variável PHP.

aqui o arquivo load.js.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#botao').click(function(){
        $('#aguarde, #blanket').css('display','block');
    });

  $("input:radio").click(function() {    

  var cor = $(this).val();

    var correio = cor;

     $.post("lojavirtualpoo/carrinho<-não estou sabendo colocar isso aqui",
    {
        correio: correio
    },function(){
        console.log(correio);
    });


 }); 


});
```

essa página está localizada em localhost/lojavirtualpoo/app/views/carrinho/Index.php, dentro da página Index.php tem esses código pra receber o valor mas não recebe
localhost/lojavirtualpoo/app/views/carrinho/Index.php

```
$tipo_correio = $_POST["correio"];
var_dump($tipo_correio);
```

código html na mesma página

```
<td>

 <span class="tt1">Opção</span>

 <?php if ($cep_destino != "") { ?>

 <span class="tt2"><input type="radio" name="correio" value="pac"> 1</span>

 <span class="tt2"><input type="radio" name="correio" value="sedex"> 2</span>

 <?php } else { ?>

 <span class="tt2">Nenhum resultado</span>

 <?php } ?>

</td>
```

aqui vai uma imagem pra vcs entenderem melhor o que eu quero
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acessando diretamente a url `lojavirtualpoo/carrinho` funciona?

Comment: funciona sim, no console quando clico umas das duas opções aparece no console pac ou sedex

Comment: Pode ser que está dando erro. Ve na aba network do devtools a resposta do request

Comment: verifiquei o status está 200 como ok, eu clico em uma das opções e no console aparece normal, mas na parte de receber a variável no php $tipo_correio não recebe o valor...

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: correio in C:\wamp64\www\lojavirtualpoo\app\views\carrinho\Index.php on line 2

Comment: Já tentou colocar na URL do Ajax o caminho absoluto: `http://localhost/lojavirtualpoo/app/views/carrinho/Index.php`?

Comment: sim já testei e não funcionou, estou estudando para saber onde está o erro, vcs vão querer deixar em aberto? ou é melhor fechar? Tenho certeza que se eu me dedicar mais um pouco em dominar de vez essas tecnologia eu vou saber fazer o que eu quero...

Answer (score -1):

Carlos, ficou meio confuso  a pergunta, porém elaborei esse fluxo...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#botao').click(function(){
        $('#aguarde, #blanket').css('display','block');
    });

  $("input:radio").click(function() {  
    let cor = $(this).val();
    let correio = cor;
 
    let tipoFrete = ''; // id ou string com tipo de frete

    $.ajax({
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'rota de busca do cep',
 data: {frete: tipoFrete},
 dataType: 'JSON',
 })
 .done(function (response) {
   // executa alguma ação após a ação no servidor for efetivada com sucesso
 })
 .fail(function(error) {
   console.error(error)
 })

   }); 


});
```